# SQL "not in" assistance

Tags: sql-server

Orderinfo Table

```
OnlineOrderID | Code
123 | apple
123 | banana
234 | banana




select * from Orderinfo
where code not in ('apple')
```

I want to return:

```
234 | banana
```

but I am getting

```
123 | banada
234 | banana
```

Comment: check that `code` isn't padded with invisible characters, e.g. what does `select len(Code) ...` show? if it's not 5, then your `apple` isn't really `apple`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orderinfo o
WHERE o.OnlineOrderID NOT IN (SELECT OnlineOrderID FROM Orderinfo WHERE Code = 'apple')
```

This will give you orders that do not have an apple.